# How do I invert the order of a TreeView?

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

This question seems so simple, yet I didn't find any feasible solution after searching for it all day long.

I have a standard TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyUpsideDownTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Items is a list (I need the list to stay in this order) like

- A
- B

  - B1
  - B2
- C

I want my TreeView to show the items (including all subitems!) in an inverted order, i.e.

- C
- B

  - B2
  - B1
- A

Sorting doesn't seem to be the solution since I don't want to compare the items' value.

A converter...?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: uh? this quesion asked Aug 31, 2018 at 16:22? Are you tripping over this question again, dude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great example of the fundamental theorem of software engineering - any problem can be solved with an extra layer of abstraction.

Since you can't modify the way the underlying collection operates, and you can't force `TreeView` to reverse the items on its own (well, you could, but not without retemplating it), a solution is to introduce an intermediate "view" (more like a database view rather than the MVVM kind) that wraps the underlying collection and sits between it and the `TreeView`.

Such a "view" could be implemented like this:

```
public class ReverseListView : ICollection, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private IList _collection;

    public ReverseListView(IList collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
        if (collection is INotifyCollectionChanged incc)
            incc.CollectionChanged += this.OnSourceCollectionChanged;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _collection.Cast<object>().Reverse().GetEnumerator();
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged;

    public int Count => this._collection.Count;

    public bool IsSynchronized => this._collection.IsSynchronized;

    public object SyncRoot => this._collection.SyncRoot;

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        this._collection.CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    private void OnSourceCollectionChanged(
        object? sender,
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs reversedArgs = e;
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            reversedArgs = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                e.Action,
                e.NewItems,
                this._collection.Count - e.NewStartingIndex - 1);
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            reversedArgs = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                e.Action,
                e.OldItems,
                this._collection.Count - e.OldStartingIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle other collection changed actions if needed
        }
        this.CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, reversedArgs);
    }
}
```

And a value converter:

```
public class ReverseListConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is IList list))
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        return new ReverseListView(list);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Unlike the other answers this approach doesn't modify the original collection or create and maintain a separate copy - which in one of the other answers would lead to errors if the converter instance is used in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for multiple tree members, as it isn't stateless. Instead it operates as a view or abstraction of the underlying collection but just inverts the order during enumeration. If the underlying collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (it doesn't have to) then it also subscribes to the collection change events and raises its own events with the inverted indices. Note I didn't try to handle multi-item changes as these aren't supported by `ObservableCollection` or WPF.

A quick test demonstrates that the `TreeView` displays the items in the reverse order and correctly responds to changes in the underlying collection, and no special binding conditions like `OneTime` are necessary:

**XAML**

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_window, Path=ViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Click="AddPersonClick">Add Person</Button>
        <Button Click="RemovePersonClick">Remove Person</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    
    <TreeView Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding People, Converter={StaticResource ReverseListConverter}}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Converter={StaticResource ReverseListConverter}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, params string[] children)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        foreach (var child in children ?? Array.Empty<string>())
        {
            this.Children.Add(new Person(child));
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ObservableCollection<Person> _Children;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Children
    {
        get => _Children ?? (_Children = new ObservableCollection<Person>());
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.People.Add(new Person("Daenerys", "Drogon", "Rhaegal", "Viserion"));
        this.People.Add(new Person("Ned", "Robb", "Sansa", "Arya", "Bran", "Rickon"));
        this.People.Add(new Person("Cersei", "Joffrey", "Myrcella", "Tommen"));
    }

    ObservableCollection<Person> _People;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get => _People ?? (_People = new ObservableCollection<Person>());
    }
}

public partial class ReverseListDemo : Window
{
    public ReverseListDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new ViewModel();

    private void AddPersonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.People.Add(
            new Person($"Person {this.ViewModel.People.Count}"));
    }

    private void RemovePersonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.People.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Initial state:

[image]

After adding a new person to the end of the list:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this exhaustive and well-written answer. This indeed seems to finally tackle my issue. 

Comment: @Christoph142 sweet, I think that's my first bounty! Thanks for following up and very glad to have helped. Looks like the issue has been plaguing you for awhile. FYI I had an arthimetic bug in the collection change handler that I just fixed; need to subtract 1 from the count in the Add handler. This is why I should never edit code in an answer without re-testing it. :) Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I had actually noticed it reading through your answer. It's not a project that I'm currently actively working on. Hence the silence for a few years. But I plan on revisiting it and seemingly basic issues like this sometimes just drive me nuts over time. Not being able to tick it, you know? So thanks again for easing my mind. 

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? (Im assuming your `Items` binding is a List.)

Converter:

```
public class ReverseListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var list = (List<object>)value;

        list.Reverse();

        return list;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ReverseListConverter x:Key="ReverseListConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<TreeView x:Name="MyUpsideDownTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource ReverseListConverter}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. It looks like it gets screwed up whenever I add new items to the list. I'd expect an "Add()" to make the item appear at the top, but it does continue to appear at the bottom of the Tree.

Comment: When inserting items you could try Items.Insert(0, itemToAdd) which will add the item at the start of your list.

Comment: @Christoph142 Also when adding items are the new items displaying in your UI or are you only able to see the new item by debugging your code? If they aren't displaying in the UI try changing your List to an ObservableCollection<> and the calling RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items) after you have added to it.

Comment: It **is** an ObservableCollection and the items do appear immediately, but at the end of the list. And as I said before, I need the list to stay in its proper order. Inserting new items at index 0 isn't an option as the same list gets used in another location in its original order. It looks like the converter only gets the new item instead of the whole list and hence Reverse() doesn't change anything here...

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to insert the item into a *new* collection i.e. a second reversed source collection.
If the source collection is an `INotifyCollectionChanged` like the `ObservableCollection` then you can monitor collection changes and update the reversed collection accordingly. You can implement an `IValueConverter` or an attached behavior to provide the reversed collection. Or directly add this collection to the binding source. For example, if you want to use the reversed collection in multiple places where each `ItemsControl` must have it's own collection instance, then an `IValueConverter` might be the better option.

Otherwise, my first choice would be to implement the second reversed collection (and reverse logic) directly in the binding source.
But if reusability is important or the reversed collection is only required for the UI, then I would prefer the `IValueConverter`.

If the source collection is not an `INotifyCollectionChanged` collection then you would have to replace the complete collection instance in order to update the binding (not recommended) or introduce a second collection as the binding source (and avoiding the converter). You would have to maintain two collections anyways so it doesn't really matter where the second collection is defined.

However, the key is to *add* to the original collection and to *insert* to the reversed collection copy.

Alternatively, you can consider sorting the items (ascending/descending) via the `CollectionView`. This would eliminate the second collection. Sorting would make sense if the original collection is ordered. Sorting will generally perform worse than a simple insert.

The following example shows a converter that provides the second reversed collection. the converter observes the original collection to update the reversed source (add/remove/clear).
I strongly recommend to use an `ObservableCollection` as source, modify a single collection instance instead of replacing it, and to set the `Binding.Mode` to `OneTime`:

**ReverseCollectionConverter.cs**

```cs
public class ReverseCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
  private ConditionalWeakTable<INotifyCollectionChanged, ObservableCollection<object>> ReverseCollectionMap { get; }
    = new ConditionalWeakTable<INotifyCollectionChanged, ObservableCollection<object>>();

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (value is IEnumerable<object> enumerable)
    {
      IEnumerable<object> initialReversedItemsCopy = enumerable.Reverse();
      var reversedCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(initialReversedItemsCopy);
      if (enumerable is INotifyCollectionChanged iNotifyCollectionChangedCollection)
      {
        _ = this.ReverseCollectionMap.TryAdd(iNotifyCollectionChangedCollection, reversedCollection);
        CollectionChangedEventManager.AddHandler(iNotifyCollectionChangedCollection, OnCollectionChanged);
      }

      return reversedCollection;
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  private void OnCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    INotifyCollectionChanged iNotifyCollectionChangedCollectionSource = (INotifyCollectionChanged)sender;
    if (!this.ReverseCollectionMap.TryGetValue(iNotifyCollectionChangedCollectionSource, out ObservableCollection<object> reversedCollection))
    {
      return;
    }

    int lastIndexOfReversedCollection = reversedCollection.Count - 1;
    switch (e.Action)
    {
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        foreach (object? item in e.NewItems)
        {
          reversedCollection.Insert(0, item);
        }

        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
        int reversedRemoveIndex = lastIndexOfReversedCollection - e.OldStartingIndex;
        foreach (object? item in e.OldItems)
        {
          reversedCollection.RemoveAt(reversedRemoveIndex);
        }

        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
        reversedCollection.Clear();
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>

  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeDataItems, 
                                  Mode=OneTime, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource ReverseCollectionConverter}}">

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeDataItem}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Children, 
                                                      Mode=OneTime, 
                                                      Converter={StaticResource ReverseCollectionConverter}}">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </TreeView>
</Window>
```